# Conveniently and temporarily modify a Spring property in an application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

At times, we want to override a property in a Spring `application.properties` file when we're running unit tests or an application.

Assume `gradle` manages the builds, and consider this test module, in `MinimalValueTest.java`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MinimalValueTest {

    @Value("${test.property}")
    String testProperty;

    @Test
    public void test() {
      Assertions.assertTrue(testProperty != null);
      // Support a test that changes the value of test.property at the command line to "property_set_by_override_at_the_command_line"
      // (Unfortunately, org.junit.jupiter version 5 doesn't support this directly.)
      Boolean oneOfTheExpectedValues = (testProperty.equals("a_test_property") ||
                                        testProperty.equals("property_set_by_override_at_the_command_line"));
      Assertions.assertTrue(oneOfTheExpectedValues);
    }

}
```

This test references this property defined in the `src/test/resources/application.properties` file:

```
test.property=a_test_property
```

**What `gradle` command can be used to override this value of `test.property`?**

Several existing SO questions try, but fail, to solve this problem: [Override default Spring-Boot application.properties settings in Junit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29669393), [Problems passing system properties and parameters when running Java class via Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23689054), and [Passing system properties into Spring Boot from Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39820528).

Comment: Set the property value in `application–test.properties`.

Comment: Thanks, @Unmitigated, that works! Surprisingly, Google does not find this  documented in the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables will override any properties defined in your application*.[properties|yml].  You can read the property resolution order in [the *Externalized Configuration* section of the Core Features documentation of Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Overriding properties with environment variables is pretty straightforward; you just need to follow the convention.

- Replace dots (.) with underscores (_).
- Remove any dashes (-).
- Convert to uppercase.

To override that particular environment variable on a mac/linux/unix, export it (following the above convention).

```
export TEST_PROPERTY=a_test_property
```

When your tests run, this will be the property that the property resolver will expose.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on the test to enable the "test" profile. Then, the property can be set in `application–test.properties`.